# Prove $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt2i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt2i)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to know why the following two are equivalent:

$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt2i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt2i)$$, where $\mathbb{Q}$ is the rational number field, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt2i)=a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt2i+di,a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: what does mean $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{ 2}+\sqrt{2}i)$? Define this set!

Comment: @math_man It can be defined as the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q\cup \{\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2i\}$.

Comment: @DHunter Can you prove any of the inclusions? Can you find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 2i$ over $\mathbb Q$? How does the degree of this polynomial help you?

Answer (score 3):

An inclusion is obvious:
$$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}(1+i))\subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{2})$$
and the reverse inclusion follows from:
$$\left(\sqrt{2}(1+i)\right)^2 = 4i,\qquad  \left(\sqrt{2}(1+i)\right)-i\left(\sqrt{2}(1+i)\right)=2\sqrt{2}.$$